# node.js puppeteer "document is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, document, queryselector

I am attempting to try click a button using code without an id or class, but my terminal always responds with:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("Accept Cookies");
    ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

This is my code:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const product_url = "https://www.nike.com/launch"

async function givePage() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    return page;
}

async function acceptCookies(page) {
    await page.goto(product_url);
    const btn = await page.waitForSelector('#cookie-settings-layout > div > div > div > 
div:nth-child(3) > div.ncss-col-md-6.ncss-col-sm-12.mb5-sm > button')
    await btn.click()
}

async function notifyMe(page) {
    await page.goto(product_url);
    document.querySelector("button[type=\"submit\"]").click("Notify Me");
}

async function checkout() {
    var page = await givePage();
    await acceptCookies(page);
    await notifyMe(page);
}

checkout();
```

What did I do wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: `givePage` leaks memory. Don't abandon the `browser` object or you won't be able to call `.close()` on it and the process will hang. Each of your functions re-navigates to the URL, which is sort of odd. I'd recommend not using funcs like this until the script is actually working. Can you share what you're trying to accomplish? `document.getElementsByTagName("Accept Cookies");` doesn't make much sense because `"Accept Cookies"` isn't an HTML tag, e.g. `<p>` or `<button>`. That's probably text you want to find. As others have mentioned, there's no `document` in Node -- that's a browser object.

Comment: @ggorlen Regarding my earlier comment, `givePage` can work if you use `page.browser().close()` to access the parent browser from each page it creates for closure.

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in variable in NodeJS named `document`, since it doesn't run in the browser.

If you want to access `document`, in Puppeteer there's a `page.evaluate()` function where you can access the `document` variable (as well as everything else inside client-side JS):

```js
// ...
await page.evaluate(() => {
  document.querySelector("button[type=\"submit\"]").click();
});
```

Please note though, that all the JavaScript you run will be run on the browser, not in NodeJS, so if you want to get the value back you can return:

```js
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
  var something = document.getElementById("something");
  return something.innerText; 
});
console.log(result); // will print in the console "blah blah blah"
```

Likewise if you want to pass variables to the callback you have to give them to the evaluate function:

```js
await page.evaluate((name, age) => {
  // do something with 'name' and 'age'
}, "John", 34);
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have an example on your code on how to access elements. Instead of `document.querySelector`, use `page.waitForSelector` like what you did on line 12.

```
document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]').click()
```

should be

```
(await page.waitForSelector('button[type="submit"]')).click()
```

Answer (score -1):

In Nodejs, you don't have access to web APIs like a window, document, etc. so you can't use document.querySelector to select elements here.
Instead of handling clicks on DOM elements on server side, you should handle those clicks on the client-side only and then fetch the data from the server accordingly.

Comment: While what you say is true, please consider that the OP is using Puppeteer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not familiar with Puppeteer. Maybe I should not have answered this.

Comment: That's fine, everyone makes mistakes; sometimes it's just a good idea to consider everything in the question. :)

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for the next time :)