# Puppeteer - how to execute for loop synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm writing a Puppeteer script that goes to a page that has a list of items, gets that list, clicks on each link in that list one by one, looks for a selector, clicks on that element if it's there, then goes back to the previous page.

I have a for loop that is supposed to be executed synchronously, which works for the first iteration of that loop, then on iteration 2 it appears to go completely async and runs all the rest of the iterations immediately instead of waiting each time.

Here's what I have currently:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // Login
    await page.goto('https://www.acherryontop.com/user/log_in', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
    
    let loginButton = await page.waitForSelector('#action2');
    await page.type('#email', 'email@email.com');
    await page.type('#password', 'password');

    await loginButton.click();
    await page.waitForNavigation();

    // Start
    await page.goto('https://www.acherryontop.com/shop/company/stamperia_intl', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});

    let elemList = await page.$$('[data-pid]');

    for (let i = 0; i <= elemList.length; i++) {

        let pointsExist = !! await page.$('#hunt_progress_number');

        if (pointsExist) {
            let currentItem = elemList[i];

            // This has to be wrapped in a try or it errors on second iteration
            try {
                await currentItem.click({waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
            catch {
                console.log('Failed to click');
            }

            // If element is here, click on it
            try {
                let point = await page.$('#hunt > img');
                await point.click({waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
            } catch {
                console.log('Point not found, going back...');
            }

            // Go back and click on the next item
            await page.goBack({waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
        }
    }
})();
```

It will click the current item in the list, go to that page, perform the check, go back to the previous page, then immediately execute the rest of the for loop iterations. I'm sure this has something to do with not making this synchronous properly. I tried extracting the loop out into an async function, but experienced the same behavior. How do you force it to wait on each iteration of the loop?

Comment: It's impossible to make async code sync, so the solution is [something other than you assume](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). Can you provide the actual site so the example is reproducible? Thanks. The code appears to `await` all promises and isn't falling into a [`forEach` trap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop), so my guess is that `if (pointsExist) {` is false on iterations after the first. You might need to `waitForSelector` there, or handle some page-specific behavior properly.

Comment: Based on my understanding of Puppeteer and this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71368256/why-are-almost-all-puppeteer-calls-asynchronous yes Puppeteer is asynchronous by default, but you can have operations perform synchronously by just awaiting all calls that you need to wait for.

Comment: That doesn't make the code synchronous per se, it just makes the asynchronous code serial/sequential rather than parallel, which it looks like your script correctly does. Whether it matches the necessary actions to automate whatever page you're automating is uncertain, but that's probably where the problem is. Can you provide a reproduction of the page that's runnable? Probably not, but it's really hard to debug a page I can't actually see. One tip I can offer in general is that `goBack()` is usually less reliable than `goto()` for this sort of pattern, but it depends on the site.

Comment: The actual site is a shop with pages that have a list of products https://www.acherryontop.com/shop/company/stamperia_intl

So click on one, look for a selector (#hunt), if it's not there, go back, repeat. This selector doesn't appear unless you're logged into an account though.

Comment: Other tips: `await page.waitForNavigation();` needs to be set before clicking and `let elemList = await page.$$('[data-pid]')` will probably be stale after the first loop. I'm pretty sure you'll need to reselect this each time. Handles don't persist after navigation. BTW, when the loop "goes synchronous", do any logs print or not? If so, which branches is it taking?

Comment: Ah OK I'm pretty sure that's exactly what it is, I thought my list would be fine if it was stored into memory as a variable. Let me try rehydrating the list every time.

Comment: It is in memory, but the underlying elements the handles point to on the page are destroyed after each nav.

Comment: That was it, thank you so much! That was a critical piece of understanding I was missing from Puppeteer. Please feel free to write as an answer, I don't want to take the credit!

Comment: Glad you worked it out. It's OK, go ahead and write a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). I'll add another if I have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is the following common antipattern, simplified for illustrative purposes:

```js
// Grab elements from product list page P
let elemList = await page.$$('[data-pid]');

for (let i = 0; i < elemList.length; i++) {
  // Click elemList[i] to navigate to product detail page P[i]
  // Grab info from product detail page P[i]

  // Go back to the root page P to prepare to click the next item
  await page.goBack({waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
}
```

This works fine on the first iteration, but since `elemList` refers to an array of elements that were almost certainly destroyed on navigation away from the root page, the second and subsequent elements will be stale and no longer point to anything. Unlike [locators](https://pptr.dev/guides/locators/), `$$` doesn't re-query upon use.

One solution is to re-query every time you get back to the root page:

```js
// Just see how many detail elements there are
const count = await page.$$eval('[data-pid]', els => els.length);

for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  const elemList = await page.$$('[data-pid]'); // Re-query
  // Click elemList[i] to navigate to product detail page P[i]
  // Grab info from product detail page P[i]

  // Go back and click on the next item
  await page.goBack({waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
}
```

This assumes the number of products on a page is fixed, which is the common case. If it's not, then re-query the count on each iteration too.

---

A couple other pointers and issues:

- `<=` should be `<` in your loop.
- Try to avoid element handles when possible. So:

  ```
  let point = await page.$('#hunt > img');
  await point.click({waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
  ```

  can be

  ```
  await page.click("#hunt > img");
  ```
- `waitUntil` isn't an option on `page.click()`. `page.click()` doesn't wait for navigations, so it usually needs to be coupled with a `waitForNavigation()`, assuming you're not waiting for a predicate on the next page. See the next point for the correct `click`/`waitForNavigation` combo.
- The following code causes a race condition, a [common gotcha](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#not-using-promiseall-when-triggering-navigation-with-a-click):

  ```
  await loginButton.click();
  await page.waitForNavigation();
  ```

  If the navigation resolves quickly, before `await page.waitForNavigation()` runs, it'll time out and throw. The prescribed approach is:

  ```
  const nav = page.waitForNavigation(); // no await but begin listening for nav
  await loginButton.click(); // trigger nav
  await nav;
  ```

  In many cases, waiting for a selector on the next page is a better approach rather than `waitForNavigation()` though, and in that case the normal promise flow will work as you expect, without pre-setting a promise.
- Always use a `finally` block to close the browser in the presence of an error.
- When logging errors, always print the stack trace. Only printing "Failed to click" doesn't really tell you what the actual problem is, making it difficult to debug.

Final piece of advice: when scraping, there's no need to behave exactly as a human would. Instead of using `click`, `waitForNavigation` and `goBack`, I prefer to use `goto`, which tends to be more reliable. Most elements that trigger navigation are anchors with a URL, so it's generally best to just extract that URL, then use the string in a `goto`. Instead of `goBack()`, I typically use `goto(mainPageURL)`. Applying this to the above example gives the following pseudocode:

```js
// start on root page
await page.goto(rootProductListPageUrl, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});

// Get all URLs we need to scrape details for
const detailUrls = await page.$$eval(
  ".product-detail-link" /* or whatever your product selector is */,
  els => els.map(e => e.href)
);

for (const url of detailUrls) {
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  // Grab info from product detail page P[i]

  // Go back to the root page to prepare to click the next item
  await page.goto(rootProductListPageUrl, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
}
```

I don't think this works on the page in question because you're clicking buttons that don't have hrefs, but as a general pattern, it's worth keeping in mind.